# How to use SVG in Expo SDK 40 React Native with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, svg, expo

I tried to use a svg in expo sdk 40 width : react-native-svg-transformer

Here is the process i followed :

- expo init test (typescript model with navigation)
- https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer

I got an error saying : it was expected string type but received a number

I want to use this svg :
[example vsg drawing by logiciel adobe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdVBQ.png)

Before the SDK 40, the process was working
Thanks for Help !

Comment: Could you provide additional details with code around what's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

[SVG in Expo SDK 40](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/svg/)

`react-native-svg` allows you to use SVGs in your app, with support for interactivity and animation.

```
expo install react-native-svg


import * as React from 'react';
import Svg, { Circle, Rect } from 'react-native-svg';

export default function SvgComponent(props) {
  return (
    <Svg height="50%" width="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" {...props}>
      <Circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="blue" strokeWidth="2.5" fill="green" />
      <Rect x="15" y="15" width="70" height="70" stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" fill="yellow" />
    </Svg>
  );
}
```

**How to use svg files in React-Native with Typescript**
 [Click here](https://dev.to/vinipachecov/how-to-use-svg-files-in-react-native-with-typescript-1bn7)